# Setting up an async method

Tags: c#, asynchronous

I have a C# function that currently looks like this:

```
public void Execute()
{
  // Query Database
  // Process records.
}
...
myObject.Execute();
```

Now, I want to migrate this code over to be asynchronous since its hits a database via `SqlCommand`. In an attempt to do this, I wrote the following:

```
public async void Execute() 
{
  // Query Database
  // Process records.
}
...
await myObject.Execute();
```

However, after researching this more, everyone says "avoid `async void`! it will crash your system." Ok, but what's the alternative in my case? Would it be

```
public async Task Execute()
{
  // Query Database
  // Process records.
  return null;
}
...
await myObject.Execute();
```

How can I use `async` in the case where my method doesn't return anything (it might throw an `Exception`).

Comment: You could just try this code, you know.

Comment: Yeah, and who is everyone? lets have some names. The guy named Everyone I know has no problems using async.

Comment: `async void` is generally used for event handlers. I'm not really sure who this "everyone" is but even Microsoft says that async void has its uses. [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh524395.aspx#BKMK_VoidReturnType). In your case though Servy's explanation below is probably what you are looking for.

Comment: You didn't show the code but just a FYI if you never use the word `await` inside the code that would go in `// Query Database` or in `// Process records.` you are doing something wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The return type of the method should be `Task` but there should be no `return` statements in the body of the `async` method.  The method should only use `return` if you are returning a `Task<T>` and the task itself will have a result.

A `Task` is a task that *has no result* (but indicates when it's done and propagates exceptions) and so a void method, which is a method that *has no result* (but indicates when it's done and propagates exceptions) is the asynchronous counterpart.